# How to send logs from Gitlab Pipeline jobs to Graylog?

Tags: docker, gitlab, graylog, gelf

I need to send logs like [those](https://ibb.co/GxN6MF2) from jobs executed in Gitlab pipeline to Graylog. Is it possible to do it straight from Gitlab runner containers?

I have a docker installed on my Virtual Machine with one Gitlab runner container and I would like to send job logs from Docker to Graylog server. I checked [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/gelf/) and set logging driver to gelf in /etc/docker/daemon.json like this.

```
{
  "log-driver": "gelf",
  "log-opts": {
    "gelf-address": "udp://10.10.10.4:12201"
  }
}
```

I receive some logs from this runner container but there are no any logs from Gitlab Pipeline's jobs execution. It seems like runner containers doesn't store those logs? I tried `docker logs gitlab-runner` command on another machine without gelf driver and it doesn't show logs from jobs either. Is there some way to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Job traces are sent to GitLab and stored as artifacts. If you self-host gitlab, you can forward the logs from your GitLab server using the [log forwarder](https://docs.graylog.org/docs/forwarder). By default, the logs will be with other artifacts under `var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/artifacts`

Job logs are otherwise not present in the runner.